# What font is used for OmniROM's logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo

I tried to look for it but I end up with no matching results :( Anyone know what font is used in this logo?

[image: OmniROM logo]

Comment: Looks like custom hand-drawn lettering to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be pretty close to Scriber (a little blurry around the letter curves, it looks like someone blurred/tweaked them rasterized):

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/northernblock/scriber/regular/

I ran the image through their font analyzer:

http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: Hi! I managed to try and see all other font look alikes on the second link you provided me, thanks alot!